# Creating an IAM policy attached to a user restricting user from creating custom managed policy with some actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need to create an IAM policy and this policy will be attached to a user. What I want is that, user with this policy is able to create new IAM roles and custom policies but I don't want user to create any custom policy with actions like iam:* or admin policies. For example:

My policy contains statement

```
        {
        "Sid": "LimitIamRoleAndPolicyAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
            "iam:CreatePolicy",
            "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
            "iam:CreateRole"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnNotEquals": {
                "iam:PolicyArn": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess",
                    "arn:aws:iam::*:group/Administrators",
                    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMFullAccess"
                ]
            }
        }
```

The above statement is restricting user from attaching IAMFullAccess permission on role but the user is able to create a custom policy and give json as below which allows accessing all iam services

```
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iam:*",
   "Resource": "*"
}
```

or even worse he is can create policy like

```
{
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "*",
   "Resource": "*"
}
```

which give access to everything. How can I restrict them from creating such policies. It is important for me that they do have iam:CreatePolicy permission but they should not be able to create above polices.

Answer (score 3):

Use the 'iam:permissionboundary' condition on the user's policy's "iam:CreateUser" permission

```
"Condition": {"StringEquals": 
                {"iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:policy/XCompanyBoundaries"}}
```

Your scenario is identical [to this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html)